# I need to upload a video file to a web server iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-video

I need to upload a video file to a web server iphone sdk.  It is just a quicktime movie.

Comment: I charge $50/hr for programming services, $20/hr for healthcare (I'm in the US), and $5/hr for beer (healthcare related).  If interested, please reply.  Otherwise, I would suggest asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Do you have any examples of that?

Answer (score 0):

ASIHttpRequest is your friend. 
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#streaming